# 404 error when trying to access url to post using spring boot

Tags: android, angularjs, post, spring-boot, retrofit2

Good evening, I have the following code to the implementation of a rest / teste123 service, and to call this method from the angular-js code, already authenticated with Basic authentication with spring-boot I have access to this service.
When I try to access it from the retrofit2 in my android or postman extension of chrome, I get 404.
Someone explain me what I am doing wrong.
Just to make it clear that I am pointing to the correct ip pc is 192.168 .... and not to localhost at the time of the calls.
Thank you.

```
@RestController
public class TesteController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/teste123", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Programa test(@RequestBody Programa prog) {
        System.out.println(prog);
        return new Programa();
    } 
}
```

following the example code in AngularJS that works.

```
$http.post("/teste123", {id: 'asd', txtPrograma: 'adsadasd'})
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }, function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
```

Here the interface used on android.

```
public interface ExecucaoService {

@POST("execucao/gravaLote")
public Call<Programa> gravaLote(@Body Programa programa);}
```

and to add the credentials in the header Retrofit made as follows.

```
        private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrlWS)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
        String credentials = username + ":" + password;
        final String basic = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

        httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request original = chain.request();

                Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                        .header("Authorization", basic)
                        .header("Accept", "application/json")
                        .method(original.method(), original.body());
                Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });
      OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(client).build();
    // retrofit.create(serviceClass); aqui pego a instancia do serviço criada.
```

I still have hope that is not retrofit of the problem or the postman, but a setting that did in sptring-boot.
Apologize for the English, I'm using google translate.

Comment: found that removing the spring-boot-security him to give the 404 error.
This can be bug-boot spring-security?

Comment: Could you please post your application.properties/yml ?

Comment: I'm getting the users of the postgres, I debug and ok, working. For the angular with web application works correctly.
and I have no user settings and password on aplication.properties

Comment: Not solved the problem of authentication, the culprit is the spring-security, just implementing a filter for minimum security since it's a college work and gave up to find real problem, tightened deadlines.